# Why do we include $\int_G |f(x-y) g(y)|dy < \infty$ in convolution's definition?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, definition, convolution

The following is extracted from 'Fourier Analysis on Groups' by Rudin, page $4,$ under the section 'Convoluton':

LCA denotes locally compact abelian.

> For any pair of Borel functions $f$ and $g$ on the LCA group $G,$
>    define their **convolution** $f * g$ by the formula  $$(f*g)(x) =
>  \int_G f(x-y)g(y) dy,$$ provided that  $$\int_G |f(x-y) g(y)|dy <
>  \infty.$$

Question: Why do we need 
$$\int_G |f(x-y) g(y)|dy < \infty$$
in the definition of convolution? W

What will happen if we defined convolution without it?

Comment: The integral is not defined?

Comment: Can give an example?

Comment: $f\equiv 1$ and $g$ not integrable on $G$, for instance. The condition is basically asking that the Borel function $h_x\colon y\mapsto f(x-y)g(y)$ you want to integrate be, in fact, integrable (that's the definition of integrability).

Comment: You are in a measure space! By definition, $\int_Xf\, d\mu$ exists iff $\int_X|f|\, d\mu < \infty.$